# Why is my ogg bigger than my m4a?

Tags: codec, ffmpeg, ogg, m4a, vorbis

I am using the following commands to encode an audio file to m4a & ogg formats:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i 0123456789 -ab 192k out.m4a
ffmpeg.exe -i 0123456789 -f wav - | oggenc2.exe - -r -q 6 -o out.ogg
```

(0123456789 has no extension.)

My m4a output is 14,608kB while my ogg output is 19,809kB.

Why? AFAIK `-q 6` is roughly 192kbps. So it should be about even. I could see one file being 1-3MB bigger than the other, but 5MB is pretty large. The m4a is almost 75% of the ogg!  Why is this?

Comment: you're comparing lossy audio compression formats; they do different things to achieve their compressions.  "-q 6 is roughly 192kb" captures the crux -- it's "roughly" equivalent according to some subjective tests, but there's no objective proof that a quality level in one codec is the equal of a quality level in another.

Comment: what format is the 0123456789 source?

Comment: @Shevek: Any, i cant remember what format it was in this test. Possibly flac, maybe aac.

Answer (score 2):

> -q 6 is roughly 192kb

You are specifying a variable bit rate for the ogg, and fixed bit rate for the m4a.  While the variable bit rate is *nominally* 192kb, it is not guaranteed to be 192kb, and for especially complex music, it will be larger.

Answer (score 1):

-q 6 has a *target* of ~192 kbit/s but will actually range from ~192 kbit/s to ~224 kbit/s so if your file is particularly complex it will tend toward the higher end

Info from [Hydrogen Audio](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Recommended_Ogg_Vorbis#Recommended_Encoder_Settings)

Answer (score 1):

Using a quality setting like "-q 6" the encoder will fluxuate the bitrate to keep a certain quality. Certain quality settings may commonly produce a particuarl bitrate (6 may usually end up being 192k) but it will depend on the sound being encoded.